# How to install ansible on amazon aws?

Tags: ansible

Having trouble running Ansible on the latest version of amazon linux.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-11 ec2-user]# yum install ansible --enablerepo=epel
[root@ip-10-0-0-11 ec2-user]# ansible-playbook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 44, in <module>
    import ansible.playbook
ImportError: No module named ansible.playbook
```

Using AMI ID: ami-a10897d6.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It appears that python library files do not have correct permissions by default. Running this fixed it for me.

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-11 ansible]# pip install ansible
```

Answer (score 5):

Using pip (alone, not in conjunction with yum) is probably the best option right now on Amazon Linux. I'd suggest getting rid of the yum-installed copy if it's still there.

The RPM specs in epel and epel-testing (as of 1.9.2) currently handle only RHEL, Fedora, and SuSE, and the defaults are installing everything under Python 2.6, where the latest Amazon Linux has default Python 2.7. A bit of work will be required to get the RPM install working under Amazon Linux...

Comment: Which means typing in  `# pip install ansible`

Comment: But `pip` is not installed Amazon linux by default.

Answer (score 5):

For Amazon Linux2 AMI:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install ansible
```

or

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install ansible2
```

For Amazon Linux AMI:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install ansible --enablerepo=epel
```

For Ubuntu 18.04 AMI:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ansible
```

Note: You can install ansible using "pip".

```
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install ansible
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not check out the source code from git and and checkout the latest stable version.

```
git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
$ cd ./ansible
$ source ./hacking/env-setup
git checkout <VERSION>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just enable the below repo from the /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo file by default is disabled.

**rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras/7Server/x86_64**

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.

Comment: As we can create a new instance in AWS with Redhat 7.4 by default ansible repo i.e "rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras/7Server/x86_64" will be disabled, so we need to enable this repo.

later on you can try this should be comes in the output of command 
#yum repolist

Comment: The commands I used:
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo
# find entry titled [rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-rpms]
# change "enabled=0" to "enabled=1"
# save and quit file ":wq"
sudo yum install ansible

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://www.linuxhilinux.com/2018/09/ansible-playbook-to-create-ec2-instance.html) says that you can use `sudo amazon-linux-extras install ansible2` to install ansible on Amazon linux.

Answer (score 1):

On Amazon Linux 2 to get the latest version of Ansible do not use yum (currently it won't give you 2.10.x), I recommend you use python3-pip.

```
sudo yum remove ansible
sudo yum install -y python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip # Do not run pip as sudo. Do this instead.
python3 -m pip install ansible
```

If you don't already have python3 you may need this step before the above:

```
sudo yum install -y python3.7
```

In my case, I needed ansible 2.10.x because it has the added benefit of requirements.yml files being able to install collections directly from git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of @M.Rajput's answer.  I wanted to define the details so I wouldn't forget.

Warning: this was only tested on a RHEL 7.7 Community AMI (ami-029c0fbe456d58bd1).

```
# modify yum repo enabled
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat-rhui.repo

# find entry titled [rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-extras-rpms]
# change "enabled=0" to "enabled=1"
# save and quit file (vim command is :wq)
sudo yum install ansible
```